# reading selected data from an excel and creating and writing to an xml in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, wpf, windows-services

I am having an .xls file containg 5 columns (id, name, address, phone, mobile) and respective values. I have to create a xml file programatically and write the 3 out of 5 column values only (id, name , mobile) in the xml file.

I am using below code to get the data from web and first writing it to an xls file which is working fine. However getting data from xls and creating and writing to xml is missing..

```
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(DownloadedxlsFilePath, FileMode.Create);

            int ReadCount = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            while (ReadCount > 0)
            {
                fs.Write(buffer, 0, ReadCount);
                ReadCount = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
            ResponseDescription = response.StatusDescription;
            fs.Close();
            stream.Close();
```

so there are two ways:
1. Get the whole data and select the required one and then create and write to an xml
2. Write the data to an .xls file easily using above code and then get the required data using C# logic and then write to xml.

Can any one help on either of above mentioned approach in c#.

Answer (score 0):

This may help, but will require some modification on your part.  I use the below code to retrieve data from an Excel file, write it to a datatable, and then iterate over each row in the datatable and write it out to a database table.

```
namespace CopyExcel
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var fileName = string.Format("{0}\\MaintList.xlsx", "C:\\Import");
            var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;", fileName);
            var db = new ModulesDataContext();
            var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [WCR$]", connectionString);
            var ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds, "ExcelData");

            DataTable ExcelData = ds.Tables["ExcelData"]; // datatable to store retrieved Excel data
            var counter = 0;
            foreach (DataRow row in ExcelData.Rows)
            {
                Module mod = new Module(); // this is the class built over my Module table

                mod.SystemID = Convert.ToInt32(ExcelData.Rows[counter]["SysID"]);
                mod.Module1 = ExcelData.Rows[counter]["Num"].ToString();
                mod.Title = ExcelData.Rows[counter]["Title"].ToString();
                mod.Type = "CAI";

                // Save data to Module database table
                db.Modules.InsertOnSubmit(mod);
                db.SubmitChanges();
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could modify so that instead of writing to datatable, you could output to XML:

```
var xElement = new XElement("systemid", Convert.ToInt32(ExcelData.Rows[counter]["SysID"]);
xElement.Add(new XElement("module", ExcelData.Rows[counter]["Num"].ToString());
xElement.Add(new XElement("title", ExcelData.Rows[counter]["Title"].ToString());
etc...
```

Of course, you'd be dealing with your own columns like `id`, `name`, and `mobile`.

Comment: @ Kevin: Thanks Kevin. I need to save the xml data in an xml file too.so i ll check this out.